# Update values from multiple selected rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. Both have the same amount of rows.

Sample data:

```
Table1{
    Id, IdTable2Row
} 

Table2 {
    Id, RedChicken -- LOL
}
```

Each row of Table1 (column IdTable2Row) should get the id of 1 row of table 2 (irrelevant which one).
Table1.IdTable2Row is null in every row before the operation.

How can I do something like this?

```
UPDATE Table1 SET IdTable2Row = (SELECT Id FROM [Table2])
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: Can the id repeat? Be specific as to what output is expected?

Comment: They cannot repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update T1
set idtablerow = t2.id
from Table1 T1
inner join Table2 T2
on T1.something = T2.something
```

In your case, with no common column:

```
with T1 as
(
select Table1.*, row_number() over (order by anycolumn) rn
from Table1
)
update T1 
set idtablerow = t2.id
from T1
inner join 
(
select x1.*, row_number() over (order by id) rn
from Table2 x1
) T2
on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Should work

Comment: There are no common values to do the join (T1.something = T2.something).

Comment: Why the Over() ? I mean, the order is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to match rows 1 to 1. Here is a solution I come up with:

```
declare @Table1 table(
    Id INT, 
    IdTable2Row INT NULL
)

declare @Table2 table(
    Id INT, RedChicken varchar(10) -- LOL
)

INSERT INTO @Table1
    VALUES
    (
        1,NULL
    ),(
        2,NULL
    ),(
        3,NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @Table2
    VALUES
    (
        10,'s'
    ),(
        20,'a'
    ),(
        30,'b'
    );


SELECT * 
FROM @Table1 ;
SELECT *
FROM @Table2;


WITH cte1 AS
(
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER by Id)  AS rown
,Id
,IdTable2Row
FROM @Table1
),
cte2 AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER by Id) AS rown
 ,Id
 ,RedChicken
FROM @Table2
)
UPDATE t
SET IdTable2Row = c2.Id
FROM @Table1 t
JOIN cte1 c1 ON c1.Id = t.Id
JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.rown = c2.rown

SELECT *
FROM @Table1
```

Comment: +1 for declaring RedChicken. Also, the answer seems to be similar to JohnHC's and I got it working already. I will be reading a bit on each step of both answers and documentation to understand exactly how the expected results are obtained! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

IN SQL SERVER if there is common column then you can join the table and update

```
update a set a.IdTable2Row=b.Id from 
Table1 a ,Table2 b
where a.column=b.column
```

Comment: There is no common column, except the future Table1.IdTable2Row = Table2.Id